# How to include configurable swatches in Best sellers / Cart cross sell / any custom listing

Tags: configurable-product, color-swatches, cross-sells

How to include configurable swatches on other listing like cross sell , bestseller or in a custom module product listing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with injecting of this block

Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml

Like this

```
    $swatchBlock = $this->getLayout()
     ->createBlock("Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable")
     ->setTemplate("Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml");

    echo $swatchBlock->setProduct($_product)->toHtml();
```

And add the  to your page